# OWASP ESAPI SecurityWrapper filter not loading on webapp deployed in Tomcat - Throws ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, owasp, esapi

I'm integrating ESAPI to my java web application. I added the following to my web.xml according to the [ESAPI documentation](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0.1)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityWrapperDefault</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.owasp.filters.SecurityWrapper</filter-class>
 </filter>
```

I have also added the ESAPI dependency in my pom.xml. When I build and deploy the .war file, I can see the esapi .jar file inside the /WEB-INF/lib/. But when tomcat is being started, it throws a ClassNotFoundException on the SecurityWrapper class.

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SecurityWrapperDefault
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.owasp.filters.SecurityWrapper
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
```

Things I tried to recover from this issue:

1. Add the esapi-2.1.0.1.jar to the /lib folder directly just to see if the class could be found - no luck
2. Write a new dummy Filter extending the ESAPI SecurityWrapper class, hoping the class would be forced to load and added the dummy filter entry in the web.xml. - This results in the application not being able to find the dummy filter class.

   public class XSSFilter extends SecurityWrapper{
   }

If someone has an idea what's going on pls let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the jar you are using. SecurityWrapper is in package `org.owasp.esapi.filters`